# How will the CICD code pick the environment variables without .env file in Github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-actions, github-ci

I am aware that we don't commit .env file to GIT since it contains secret password of the application. Now, my question is that how come our code via CICD pipeline for this project repository will run in production without having this .env file? Because in our python file inside the project, we will be referring the secrets from this .env file and since it will not be in GIT, pipeline will fail, isn't it? For example, let's say below is the class which uses dotenv function, but since we will not check in .env file in GIT, won't this fail in CICD pipeline run saying .env file not found?

```
# settings.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution on Java language. Just add `ignoreIfMissing()` to your DotEnv configuration code.

```
private static Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().ignoreIfMissing().load();
```

And setup environment variables in CI/CD what you need.
For example in Azure we do next for Maven:

```
      - task: Maven@4
        displayName: Execute tests
        env:
          ENV_PASS: $(<put variable here, set in Variables, with password, the same like in `.env` file>)
```

Answer (score 0):

CI/CD pipelines are typically set up using tools like Jenkins that take care of the environment variables. So, all the variables that are defined in .env file can be defined in Jenkins and they will be provided when your code is run on production. load_dotenv() doesn't give any error when the .env file is not found and your code will use the environment variables set in Jenkins.